# JPA PropertyNotFoundException while accessing entity created from database view

Tags: java, jpa

I have created the entity from a database view. My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "viewrpdh")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({bla bla})
public class Viewrpdh implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "tanggal")
    private Date tanggal;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "rPDM_bulan")
    private int rPDMbulan;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "rPDM_minggu_ke")
    private int rPDMmingguke;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "rPDM_satker_kode_departemen")
    private String rPDMsatkerkodedepartemen;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "rPDM_satker_kode_unit_organisasi")
    private String rPDMsatkerkodeunitorganisasi;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "rPDM_satker_kode_satker")
    private String rPDMsatkerkodesatker;
    etc;
```

Code in my servlet:

```
 List<Viewrpdh> daftarHarian = viewrpdhFacade.aMethodUsingNamedQuery(some parameter);
 request.setAttribute("daftarHarian", daftarHarian);
```

Code in my JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="column" items="${daftarHarian}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${column.rPDMsatkerkodeunitorganisasi}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${column.rPDMsatkerkodesatker}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${column.nilaiKotor51}"/></td>
        etc
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

When I run the program, I experienced an error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'entity.Viewrpdh' does not have the property 'rPDMsatkerkodeunitorganisasi'.
```

This happens when I try to access columns with names rPDM, but this does not happen if I try to access other columns, for example: tanggal. FYI, rpdh, rpdm and satker are table in my db and those entity was generated by netbean. Please help me, and sorry for my terrible English.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
@Id
@Basic
```

from all fields.
Leave `@Id` only for `ID` field in the table.
Check if you have setters and getters.

Comment: The ID is combination of those columns. I have solve the problem, it work fine after i change those attribute names. thanks anyway